# Shiny Error: need finite 'xlim' values in barplot

Tags: r, shiny, bar-chart

I'm working on my first Shiny app, trying to make a reactive barplot and table in which the user can pick the column of a dataframe to display, however, when I run the app the

> error: need finite 'xlim' values appear

.

My data contains no NA, it is a dataframe, and I can build the non-reactive graphs using normal r commands.

My code looks like this

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage( 
  plotOutput(outputId = "bar_1"),
  tableOutput(outputId = "table_1"),
  selectInput("variable", "Select variable", c("colA"="colA", "colB"="colB", "colC"="Col C")) 
)  

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$bar_1<-renderPlot(barplot(table(Book1$'input$variable'))) 
  output$table1<-renderTable(table(Book1$'input$variable'))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The console shows

```
Warning in min(w.l) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(w.r) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning: Error in plot.window: need finite 'xlim' values
Stack trace (innermost first):
    79: plot.window
    78: barplot.default
    77: barplot
    76: renderPlot
    68: output$bar_1
     1: runApp
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For a minimum reproducible example it would be helpful to have the output of `dput(head(Book1))` as well.
That way it is more easy to help

But in your case it seems to be the indexing of the columns. try the following

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$bar_1<-renderPlot(barplot(table(Book1[input$variable]))) 
  output$table1<-renderTable(table(Book1[input$variable]))
}
```

or a little more efficient

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  current.data <- table(Book1[input$variable])
  output$bar_1<-renderPlot(barplot(current.data)) 
  output$table1<-renderTable(current.data)
}
```

Comment: You may need to put input$variable inside double square brackets (I.e. Book1[[input$variable]]) for this to work. If the application gets much larger you should also think about moving Book1[[input$variable]] to its own reactive expression. This is so it only has to do the operation once per input update. It's currently doing it twice.

Comment: Can you explain me how can you do that? Thanks

Comment: It worked! Why do you have to use the square brackets without the $ when the function is responsive? Did I sleep over the tutorial?

Comment: I've included the suggestion by @Gladwell, however, pre-calcuated the entire table.

Comment: @CamiloMonge: with the dollar sign you are trying to retrieve the column named "input$variable", whereas Book1[input$variable] would retrieve the column named as the the value . The square bracket version of "input$variable", would be Book1["input$variable"] (note the quotes)